# Why is IllegalMonitorStateException thrown despite the thread calling notifyAll owns the monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand the concept of wait() and notify() in depth.
For that I wrote a very simple program in which:

1. There is a shared String 'commonResource'
2. A producer should publish some value in this String
3. A consumer should wait until some value is actually available in this String

This is the code:

```
package com.company; 

public class Wait {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Resource resource = new Resource();

        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    resource.consume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread producerThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    resource.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();
    }
}

class Resource {

    String commonResource = new String();

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("In consume. Outside Sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (commonResource) {
            System.out.println("In consume. Inside Sync block" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            commonResource.wait();
            System.out.println(commonResource);
        }
    }

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("In Produce. Outside Sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // So that consumer executes first
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        synchronized (commonResource) {
            System.out.println("In produce. Inside sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            commonResource = "I am not empty now";
            System.out.println("Done production. I am now freeing up the resource");
            commonResource.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

After executing it, I get below exception and the code hangs:

```
In consume. Outside Sync block: Thread-0
In consume. Inside Sync blockThread-0
In Produce. Outside Sync block: Thread-1
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at com.company.Resource.produce(Wait.java:55)
    at com.company.Wait$2.run(Wait.java:23)
In produce. Inside sync block: Thread-1
Done production. I am now freeing up the resource
```

According to Java docs for [notifyAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()), the monitor is with some other thread when `notifyAll()` is executed.
But as seen from the logs and also according to my understanding, `notifyAll()` is called on `commonResource` by Thread-1 which also is the owner of the monitor on `commonResource`.

So, my question is, why is IllegalMonitorStateException thrown in this case?
Am I missing something in understanding this?

Thank you.

Comment: You keep changing the value of commonResource, so you can't synchronize on it: `commonResource = "I am not empty now"`. You should always synchronize on a final field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JBNizet said you change the `String` value which is used as a lock. That's why you are getting an `IllegalMonitorStateException`. To get rid of that use a separate `final` lock `Object` for `synchronization` like so,

```
class Resource {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    String commonResource = new String();

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("In consume. Outside Sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("In consume. Inside Sync block" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            lock.wait();
            System.out.println(commonResource);
        }
    }

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("In Produce. Outside Sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // So that consumer executes first
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("In produce. Inside sync block: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            commonResource = "I am not empty now";
            System.out.println("Done production. I am now freeing up the resource");
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```